# How to slice a pandas dataframe based on unique values of a column inside a for loop and pass every slice to a function?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I want to have a `for loop` which in its each iteration will slice  a big `pandas dataframe` `df` based on unique values of one of its columns lets say `A`, and then pass this sliced dataframe to a function which takes a dataframe as an argument lets say `fun(df)`. Basically `fun(df)` will get a new sliced dataframe with every iteration of for loop.
For eg lets say following is my dataframe:

```
A    B    C    D
1-1  an  at   23
1-2  ab  can  34
1-2  van bit  45
1-2  vd  sun  23
1-1  so  am   12
...
```

Now first iteration of for loop passes the below dataframe to `fun(df)`

```
A    B    C    D
1-1  an  at   23
1-1  so  am   12
```

and next iteration will pass this one to `fun(df)`

```
A    B    C    D
1-2  ab  can  34
1-2  van bit  45
1-2  vd  sun  23
```

and so on and so forth.

Number of iterations of for loop should be equal to the number of unique values of 'A'. Here in this case it will be 2.

How can I do this in python? I am new to it and don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, which returns an iterable object.

```
def fun(data):
    # pseudo function for a test
    print(data)

for k, d in df.groupby('A'):
    fun(d)
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C   D
0  1-1  an  at  23
4  1-1  so  am  12

     A    B    C   D
1  1-2   ab  can  34
2  1-2  van  bit  45
3  1-2   vd  sun  23
```

**Insight**

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby` returns `((key, grouped-by dataframe), ...)`.

In the line `for k, d in df.groupby('A')`, `k` and `d` are used to unpack the returned iterable. Since your desired output does not utilize the key (i.e. `1-1`, `1-2`, ...), so is the answer.

`fun` in the answer represents any hypothetical function. 
As mentioned in the question, `fun` is the function that *will get a new sliced dataframe with every iteration of for loop.* In this case, it is a simple `print` function to give a visual representation of what `df.groupby` returns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is `func(data)` exactly doing and what is k and d in the for loop.

Comment: @Prachi Updated answer. Please let me know if any part remains unclear :)

Comment: `@Chris` Can you please also tell me how to combine all these dataframes which `fun(df)` will return after every iteration  back into one other dataframe.

Comment: @Prachi try `pd.concat([func(d) for _, d in df.groupby('A')])`

Comment: It went to infinite loop :(

Comment: @Prachi It looks like there's a problem with `func(d)`. Besides, it is not recommended to ask question through the comments. I highly recommend you to post another question regarding your new problem. In the meantime, please share me how `func` is defined :)